# Excel Formula to find the first higher value

Tags: excel

In column D (Result), I would like to have the following formula.

For each Cell in column C, find in column B the first value higher than the value of the cell of column C (starting from the same row) and gives as output the difference between the values found in column A (Count).

Example:
the value in C2 is 40. the first cell of B that has a value higher than 40 is B6. So D2 takes `A6.value - A2.value = 5 - 1 = 4`.

Can it be done without the use of VBA?

[image]

Comment: What have you tried until now? Probably you could get this with MAX, MATCH and INDEX, using them in array formulas. Also, are the values in Column B unique, or could have duplicates? this is very important if you are looking for the max value.

Comment: P.S. Ok, no MAX, but indeed MATCH and INDEX

Comment: Also, your results makes no sense, following your rules, should not `D3=-1, D5=-3`?

Comment: @FoxfireAndBurnsAndBurns in case of D3: I have to find a value higher than 30 on the column B starting from the row 3; this value is in B4, so D3 takes 4-3=1.

Comment: Oh so you start searching in the same row. Now I see you edited the question

Comment: @FoxfireAndBurnsAndBurns yes it was not clear, I have explained it just now.

Comment: Then, `D5` should be 0 instead of 1, because the first higher value in column B is B5, so `A5-A5` is 0. Why is it 1?

Answer (score 4):

It can easily be accomplished with an array formula (so you have to enter the formula with <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Shift</kbd>+<kbd>Enter</kbd> ) :
`{=MATCH(TRUE;IF(B2:$B$7>C2;TRUE;FALSE);0)-1}`

Put this formula in cell D2, and just drag down. You only have to change the end of your data set (change $B$7 into the real last cell of the column with data)

The formula works as follows :

- The `IF` statement results in an array with TRUE/FALSE values that meet your criteria : `{FALSE;FALSE;FALSE;FALSE;TRUE;FALSE}`
- The `MATCH` (with the 0 switch) searches the array for the index of the first match, which is **5** in our case
- And you have to subtract 1 to get the offset to the cell where the function is placed, so this gives you **4**

So although you have to enter it as an array formula (you will get an `N/A` error without the ctrl+shift+enter), the result is just a single number.
Also, depending on your data set, you might want to add some ERROR handling in case no match has been found, e.g. just using the example data set in your question, the result in cell D5 will be `N/A` so you have to decide what value you want the result to be in such case.
And finally, I did not use the values in column A, as I assumed this is just a sequential ascending counter. If this is not the case, and you specifically want to find the difference between the corresponding values in that column, you can use the variant mentioned by Foxfire...  in one of the other answers: `=MIN(IF(B2:$B$6>C2;A2:$A$6))-A2`

Comment: Nice! Much cleaner than my answer ;-)

Comment: @MarcoVos Bedankt ! Don't we all just love array formulas ... ;))

Answer (score 1):

A slightly adjusted and shortened answer on Peter K.'s suggestion:
In D2:

```
=MATCH(TRUE,$B3:B$7>C2,0)
```

enter the formula with ctrl+shift+enter

Comment: Why you exclude B2 from the range?

Comment: Because the first is 1 not 0 + not checking the count in first column and see pic of OP in cell D5

Comment: Yeah, but OP said *starting in the same row*, but you are excluding it in yor formula. you start always 1 row below.

Comment: Anyways, I think your formula is exactly what OP needs and that OP is not explaining the question properly, so I'm upvoting it

Answer (score 0):

Something like this should work for you. First transform your range to a table.

```
=IFERROR(AGGREGATE(15,6,--([@Second]<[First])*(ROW([@Second])<=ROW([First]))/--([@Second]<[First]*(ROW([@Second])<=ROW([First])))*[Count],1) - [@Count],"")
```

In this formula the comparison between [second] and [First] starts at the same row. That means that the value in D5 is 0 and not 1. (Like @Foxfire And Burns And Burnslike stated in the comments).

Answer (score 0):

Ok, I did not post the answer waiting until OP answered why `D5` is 1 instead of 0, but my formula is also an array formula. It would be:

```
=MIN(IF(B2:$B$6>C2;A2:$A$6))-A2
```

To type this formula in array mode, you need to type it as usual, but instead of pressing <kbd>ENTER</kbd>, you need to press <kbd>CTRL</kbd>+<kbd>SHIFT</kbd>+<kbd>ENTER</kbd>

Comment: What does `SI` mean

Comment: @MarcoVos OMG!!! `SI=IF`. Thanks for that!. I posted the formula in spanish, and forgot the translation. tHANKS!